# SerialPort.DataReceived event not firing

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, serial-port

I've defined a SerialPort object as the following:

```
Public WithEvents SerialComm As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
```

SerialComm is setup and opened in the object constructor and closed when the object is disposed. My handler signature is as follows:

```
Private Sub OnComm(sender as Object, e as SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialComm.DataReceived
```

I'm trying to get a DataReceived event to fire from HyperTerminal. After sending some data, I can set a breakpoint and check the value of SerialComm.BytesToRead and see that it has updated to the proper number of bytes.

I have confirmed that the SerialPort is open and is receiving data, but I can't get the event to fire.

I've also tried manually wiring up the event (after removing the WithEvents definition) using AddHandler, but I was still unable to get the event to trigger.

What am I missing?

**Update:**

This is the class that I'm having trouble with:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class CopyCat
    Implements IDisposable

    Private RxString As String        
    Private LastReceiveTime As DateTime
    Public WithEvents SerialComm As New SerialPort

    Public Property Timeout As TimeSpan

    Public Sub New(commPort As String, timeout As TimeSpan)
        Me.Timeout = timeout
        Enable(commPort)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(commPort As String)
        Me.New(commPort, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Enable()
        CommUtilities.SetupComm(SerialComm, commPort, 115200, 8, Parity.Odd, StopBits.One, Handshake.None, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Disable()
        SerialComm.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnComm(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialComm.DataReceived
        If(DateTime.Now - LastReceivedTime > Timeout) Then RxString = ""

        Do While(SerialComm.BytesToRead > 0)
            Dim readChar As String
            Dim termChar As Char = Chr(RxString.ToByteList().XorAll())
            readChar = SerialComm.ReadChar

            RxString &= readChar
            if (readChar = termChar) Then
                SerialComm.Write((From item In GetResponse(RxString).Build()
                                    Select item.Data).ToRawString)
                RxString = ""
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Function GetResponse(commandString As String) As MessageResponse
        Dim response As MessageResponse = MessageResponse.GetMessageResponseFromByteList(commandString.ToByteList())

        if (response.GetType = GetType(GetStatusResponse)) Then
            response.DataBytes(8).Data = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 255)
            response.DataBytes(9).Data = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 255)
        End If

        Return response
    End Function

    Private disposedValue as Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                SerialComm.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?